# Java Compiling sqlite via commandline doesnt work

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to compile my program via command line using an external jar of sqlite.

This is the command im running

```
javac -cp sqlite.jar ./Controllers/*.java ./DrawingTool/*.java *.java
java src.Login
```

This should run the main class, however instead i'm getting the error

[image]

However I am getting an error that there is no suitable driver.

Comment: You need to specify a classpath that includes the sqlite driver.

Comment: Note that contrary to the linked duplicate, on Windows you need to use `;` to specify entries on the classpath, eg `java -cp .;sqlite.jar src.Login` (note that src as the package name is a bit odd, so your class layout might be wrong completely)

Comment: And in the future, please post output and error message as text, do not use screenshots where text will do.